# SQL cursor to display row one by one

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite, mysql-workbench

Hi I am trying to make an android app,please help me in my codes, it has a `table named "details"`
which has the

```
 columns 
"_ID" ,"SEX" ,"AGE" ,"NAME".
```

What i want to do is to show the *details(NAME and AGE) of SEX="MALE" and SEX="FEMALE" in two different lists* in an activity having id's list1 and list2.

Also a condition should be there to check the value in *column AGE to be equal to a particular value in the variable "age_value"* (that the user enters).   if someone could send me the code it would be very helpful,thanks in advance.

Things need:

1) Creating a cursor

2) Getting rows with AGE= agevalue into cursor

3) making position of cursor to starting point

4) checking whether SEX="MALE" or SEX="FEMALE" first row in cursor initially

5) if MALE display it in first list (id list1)

6) else if FEMALE display it in second list (id list2)

7) increment the position of cursor to next row and repeat from step 4

8) do this till all rows in cursor is taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it Step by step:

Step 1 and 2: write a proper query with Where condition for Age:

Step 3: Check if cursor has data and move to First position

Step 4: Check the gender and save that user to arraylist of String accordingly.

Skip Step 5 and 6 as of now. (After iterating to all records, and saving data in arraylist, display arraylist accordingly on screen in whichever view you want. Two ListView or LinearLayout side by side, your choice.)

Step 7: move to next and repeat step 4.

Step 8: close cursor. Return result.

So here, you can keep a class with two ArrayList, one for male users, other for female users.

```
public class UserList{
    private ArrayList<String> maleList;
    private ArrayList<String> femaleList;
    //getter setter for Arraylists  
}

//your method to get data
public UserList getUserLists (Context context, String age){
    public UserList userList = new UserList();
    public ArrayList<String> maleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> femaleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "select * from USER_INFO where AGE = ?", new String[]{age});
    if(cursor != null)
    {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                  String user_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USER_NAME"));
                  String gender = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GENDER"));
                  if(gender.equalsIgnorease("MALE"))
                      maleList.add(user_id);
                  else
                      femaleList.add(user_id);
              }while(cursor.moveToNext());
              cursor.close();
        }
    }
    userList.setMaleList(maleList);
    userList.setFemaleList(femaleList);
    return userList;
}
```

Now use the returned object of userList to retrieve lists and display on screen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thnks a lot i really mean it for ur help :-)) let me try it

Comment: @Magical, just remove the `private` from `getUserLists()` i mean when declaring the Lists

Comment: one more help please i need to call this function for getting from database to cursor in certain intervals like after every 5 minutes.Can you please edit the code for that need please. Age of the user is stored in variable age .please do help.... @MagicalPhoenixϡ